# How to add custom colors to Tensorflow object detection python model bound boxes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, data-science, object-detection

Currently i am using the standard Tensorflow object detection script which is custom trained, i would like to change the colors of the bound boxes to suit the nature of my application. However i cannot seem to find a way to do so. For example instead of drawing a green box id like to draw a red box around a detected object. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I sort of found a way - after much trouble. I found nothing documenting how to do this. 
Sort of, as some colors don't seem to work.

Open "visualizations_utils.py". Should be in Lib\site-packages\utils. 
Rows 41 to 63 are your colors.

Directly under row 164,

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image),

enter a new row

color = 'Pink'

Save it, and you have now changed the color to a pinkish color. Row 175, you can make the label text smaller.

Some colors don't seem to work, like "Red".

Answer (score 0):

1. add “color” attribute in the label map pbtxt file. i.e.

   item {
       name: "/m/01g317"
       id: 1
       display_name: "person"
       color: "Pink"
      }
2. Open  file “research/object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map.proto”. Add the following line.

   ```
   optional string color = 4;
   ```

   Be aware about the semicolon, curly braces.
3. then it is required to serialize the data, so run the following command  from research 
   folder

   ```
   protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
   ```

   Before that you must install protobuf based on your OS.
4. change the code of function “convert_label_map_to_categories”  of the file object_detection/utils/lable_map_util.py

   categories = []
     list_of_ids_already_added = []
     if not label_map:
       label_id_offset = 1
       for class_id in range(max_num_classes):
         categories.append({
             'id': class_id + label_id_offset,
             'name': 'category_{}'.format(class_id + label_id_offset)
         })
       return categories
     for item in label_map.item:

   ```
   if not 0 < item.id <= max_num_classes:
     logging.info(
         'Ignore item %d since it falls outside of requested '
         'label range.', item.id)
     continue
   if use_display_name and item.HasField('display_name'):
     name = item.display_name
   else:
     name = item.name

   if use_display_name and item.HasField('color'):
     color = item.color
   else:
     color = ''

   if item.id not in list_of_ids_already_added:
     list_of_ids_already_added.append(item.id)
     categories.append({'id': item.id, 'name': name, 'color': color})          
   return categories
   ```

5.Open the file “object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py”. Go to the function named 
  “visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array”. Add the following code

```
else:
         if classes[i] in category_index.keys():
            class_color = category_index[classes[i]]['color']
            box_to_color_map[box] = class_color
```

after the code

```
if agnostic_mode:
          box_to_color_map[box] = 'DarkOrange'
```